# Format DisplayAttribute's value with string parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a property with DisplayAttribute but the attribute's value (which is a string) needs to differ slightly depending on where the property is used. The value needs a parameter (should be substituted in place of "{0}" here)

```
[Display("This text needs to have a parameter {0}")]
public string MyProperty { get; }
```

Should I just get the value of the attribute and use string.Format(..) on it or is there a better way? I would appreciate if someone would point me in the direction of a solution to this problem.

Comment: search for how to write a custom attribute

Comment: Yes you should convert the value of the attribute to the value you want when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve dynamic formatting of the DisplayAttribute value, you can use the DisplayName property instead of the Display attribute's constructor. This allows you to provide a format string and pass the parameter dynamically when needed.

Here's an example of how you can accomplish this:

```
public class MyClass {
private string myProperty;

[Display(Name = "This text needs to have a parameter {0}")]
public string MyProperty {
get 
{
  return string.Format(DisplayName, "your parameter value");
}
}

private string DisplayName {
get {
  var displayAttribute = (DisplayAttribute) 
 TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["MyProperty"]
    .Attributes
    .OfType < DisplayAttribute > ()
    .FirstOrDefault();

  return displayAttribute?.Name ?? "MyProperty";
 }
 }
 }
```

In this example, we define a private property DisplayName, which retrieves the value of the Name property from the DisplayAttribute applied to the MyProperty property. Then, within the getter of MyProperty, we use string.Format to substitute the parameter value into the format string retrieved from DisplayName.

By using this approach, you can maintain a single DisplayAttribute definition while dynamically incorporating the desired parameter value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).